# Forming a cluster using mosquitto iot broker on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iot, amazon-elb, mosquitto

I want to form an iot broker cluster on 2 aws ec2 instances and also want to put an aws elb in front of the cluster, but I'm unaware how the broker can be deployed in cluster using docker.
I would like to deploy mosquitto in cluster mode, any help for the same will be greatly appreciated. Thanks